# Facebook Like button not showing posts on timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

Facebook like button is not showing up the posts on timeline but its updating the count though on web page. 
Here is what I was doing, click on the link button it shows  me  facebook dialog with a valid content and clicking the send is not being posted to the timeline

**code**  :

```
 <div id="facebook-like">
    <fb:like show_faces="false" href="${fbPageUrl}/product/index.jsp?productId=${product.productId}" width="200"></fb:like>
                </div>
```

JS code :

```
  <c:set var="fblaunch" value="${fb_launch}" scope="page"/>
    <c:set var="fbAppId" value="${fb_appId}" scope="page"/>
    <c:if test = "${fblaunch == 1}">
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: "${fbAppId}", status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
    };
    (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
    </script>
    </c:if>
```

Not understanding what is preventing to post comments

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Like Comments will not show up on a persons timeline, if the page fails the open graph scrape. You can go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to correct the errors. Once corrected, Like "comments" should start showing.

Comment: I found, if the page is fail in the open grapn scrap it is not shown inside the activity list. However, I could not find a way to show it in my timeline.